# Finding prime numbers in c++

Tags: c++, primes

I'm currently learning c++ for the first time and I've written a cpp bool function to find if an integer is a prime number.

The code was:

```
bool isPrime(int n) { 
    for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
        if (n % i == 0)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
}
```

However, it turns out that 9 is also considered as a prime number with this function.

I found a solution just by removing the else statement,

```
bool isPrime(int n) { 
    for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
        if (n % i == 0)
            return false;
    }
}
```

but I still don't get why the else statement had anything to do with it in the first place. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: You need the `return true` to be outside the `for` loop.  If all checks fail than it's true.  The `else` statements means it returns true the first time the test fails.

Comment: And you only need to check up to `n/2`

Comment: second version is missing `return true` at the end.

Comment: @Matt `sqrt(n)`

Comment: `9%2` is `1`.   So, on the first iteration of the loop, the first code returns `true` when `i == 2`.       More generally, the first code only ever checks `i` with a value of `2`, and immediately returns.   The loop is never executed for `i` with values greater than `2`.     The second version runs through all loop iterations, before concluding that a value is prime.

Comment: @S.M - better `isqrt(n)` - where `isqrt()` is specified as being the largest integer less than or equal to the square root.   There are plenty of algorithms for computing `isqrt()` without use of floating point.

Comment: There are undoubtedly other questions that this could be made a duplicate of.

Comment: Why is this a duplicate ?  She's not asking how to find prime numbers, she is asking what is wrong with her approach.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the `if` statement.

```
    if (n % i == 0)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
```

The condition reads "if `n` is divisible by the current number".  The condition will either be true (in which case `n` is not prime) or false (it *might* be prime) so one of the branches must be taken and the function will exit in either case, possibly prematurely.

Removing the `else` prevents early return, however, it also prevents `true` being returned by the function. You can simply add `return true` to the end of the function:

```
bool isPrime(int n) { 
    for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
        if (n % i == 0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;    // must be prime
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because it will return in the first loop!
When the function enters the else, it will return true.
Any odd number will return true — and 9 is the first odd number bigger than 1 which is not a prime.

Try this:

```
bool isPrime(int n) { 
    for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
        if (n % i == 0)
            return false;
        else
            continue;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: `else continue` is redundant - the loop will continue without it.

Comment: I know. I put it to be more explanatory.

Answer (score 1):

The only way a number is prime is when the loop completes, so the `return true;` statement should be outside the loop.  You only have to check numbers up to the square root of `n`.

Also, you need to handle the case where `n` is less than 2.

```
#include <cmath>

bool isPrime(int n)
{
    if (n < 2)
    {
        return false;
    }
    for (int i = 2; i <= sqrt(n); i++)
    {
        if (n % i == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: It's probably better to precalculate `sqrt(n)` to ensure that it is not recalculated on each iteration.  That said, the gain in performance over the original code is so dramatic that it wouldn't matter all that much — and a good optimizer might hoist the `sqrt()` call out of the loop — but it is probably better not to assume that it will.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, That's a valid point, although I think most compilers will take care of it.  I guess the loop header could be written as `for (int i = sqrt(n); i > 1; i--)`.  I think that would add more confusion than necessary considering the question that was asked, though,

Comment: You want to start at the small end; more numbers are multiples of 2 and 3 than are multiples of 29 and 31 (at least for computers and finite arithmetic — infinities are funny things).  Another optimization is to check for even outside the loop, and then have the loop only increment over odd numbers from 3.  Or you can check 2 and 3 outside the loop and then only check values of the form 6N±1 (for N = 1, 2, …).  Etc.  These do fewer modulo operations.

Comment: Another good point, but it also serves to illustrate what I just said - this is quickly getting way too complicated for the question at hand.

Comment: Agreed, and it isn't fair to pick on only your answer because others have the same (or at least similar) issues.  Actually, two of them don't even have the `sqrt()` optimization, which makes a fantastic difference even when the numbers being checked are quite small.  The other changes are definitely second-order improvements.

Answer (score 0):

9 is odd. Which means it's not divisible by 2. In fact it's the first odd number after 1 that is not prime. Your code explicitly returns true if n is not divisible by 2.

```
for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
    if (n % i == 0)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

The first time the for loop runs, `i` is 2. Either `n % i == 0` is true or it is false. If true, your function immediately returns false. If false, your function immediately returns true.

You need to move the `return true` statement outside the loop. Only after checking all possible divisors by completing the for loop do you know if the number `n` is prime.